# Error while setting up a RTMP Server - make error

Tags: 14.04, make, rtmp

Trying to set up an RTMP server on Ubuntu 14.04.4, but I am running into the above error when trying to complete the guide found [here](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/how-to-set-up-your-own-private-rtmp-server-using-nginx.50/).

I have done everything correctly I think, when trying to run this portion of the guide I get the error:

```
$ ./configure --with-http_ssl_module --add-module=./nginx-rtmp-module-master
$ make <-- Command that gives the error`
```

Error:

```
make error ** No rule to make target 'build', needed by 'default'. Stop
```

I'm still new with Linux, so i'm not really sure what I am doing wrong, any guidance would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: What error appears when you run make?

Comment: The error is tht title, sorry.

make error ** No rule to make target 'build', needed by 'default'. Stop

Comment: Running apt-get update and apt-get upgrade seemed to fix it.

Comment: @MattFogleman Hi! Please add the comment as an answer and accept it so that other users may find it useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

Update your nginx.

Using the following command, gives the error.

```
$ wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.9.15.tar.gz
```

Instead use,

```
$ wget https://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.10.1.tar.gz
```